# Alternating between two enum values

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum and I want to alternate between two values when a condition is met. At the moment, I'm using `if`/`else` to swap values, but is there some nicer one-liner way of doing this?

```
if (myEnum == MyEnum.Val1) 
    myEnum = MyEnum.Val2
else 
    myEnum = MyEnum.Val1;
```

Comment: `myenum = myEnum == MyEnum.Val1 ? MyEnum.Val2 : MyEnum.Val1`

Comment: An enum can be cast to an integer.  So you can set the enum values to to 1 and -1 and then simply multiply by -1 (or any positive/negative number).

Comment: perhaps a boolean is better for your purpose `myBoolean = !myBoolean`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ternary operation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zakwfxx4(v=vs.90).aspx:

```
myEnum = myEnum == MyEnum.Val1 ? MyEnum.Val2 : MyEnum.Val1;
```

If you want, you add brackets for readability:

```
myEnum = (myEnum == MyEnum.Val1) ? MyEnum.Val2 : MyEnum.Val1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternating between two values usually means xor-ing, so how about this:

```
myEnum ^= MyEnum.Val1 ^ MyEnum.Val2;
```

Comment: @user3791372 but the above is faster! and ?: is trivial.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is equivalent to `myEnum ^= (MyEnum)1`, right?

Comment: @MichaelHaddad It depends. If `MyEnum.Val1` ls 0 and `MyEnum.Val2` is 1, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

Depending the values of `myEnum` you can do some math tricks, but you can always use `?` operator:

```
myEnum = myEnum == MyEnum.Val1 ? MyEnum.Val2 : MyEnum.Val1;
```